# How to display coordinates as Strings with Graphics2D in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I have a Voronoi diagram being displayed thanks to the Graphics2D class. I would like to know how to display a String in one of black dots located within the patterns. I've tried things such as labels, etc., and can't manage to output a String anywhere in the diagram.

[image: output example]

Here's how the code looks:

```
public Voronoi() {
    super("Voronoi Diagram");
    setBounds(0, 0, size, size);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    int n = 0;
    
    Random rand = new Random();
    I = new BufferedImage(size, size, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    px = new int[cells];
    py = new int[cells];
    color = new int[cells];
    for (int i = 0; i < cells; i++) {
        px[i] = rand.nextInt(size);
        py[i] = rand.nextInt(size);
        color[i] = rand.nextInt(16777215);
    }
    
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            n = 0;
            for (byte i = 0; i < cells; i++) {
                if (distance(px[i], x, py[i], y) < distance(px[n], x, py[n], y)) {
                    n = i;
                }
            }
            I.setRGB(x, y, color[n]);
        }
    }

    Graphics2D g = I.createGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    for (int i = 0; i < cells; i++) {
        g.fill(new Ellipse2D .Double(px[i] - 2.5, py[i] - 2.5, 5, 5));
    }

    try {
        ImageIO.write(I, "png", new File("voronoi.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(I, 0, 0, this);
}

static double distance(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2) {
    double d;
    // d = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2)); // Euclidian
    d = Math.abs(x1 - x2) + Math.abs(y1 - y2); // Manhattan
    // d = Math.pow(Math.pow(Math.abs(x1 - x2), p) + Math.pow(Math.abs(y1 - y2), p), (1 / p)); // Minkovski
    return d;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Voronoi().setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Draw a String using a Graphics object: `g.drawString("Hello World", x, y)`

Comment: You are kidding me, what?! Thanks! :)

Comment: Tips: 1) Don't extend `JFrame`. For custom painting. Extend a `JPanel` and override the `paintComponent` method, then add it to the frame. 2) `setBounds(.., size, size);` that's the wrong size. Even if it is a correct guess for your case, it will be wrong for almost everyone else. The custom painted component should *suggest* a preferred size, then the frame be `pack()`ed around it. 3) Post a [mre]. 4) `I = new BufferedImage(..` attribute names should start with lower case. 5) An overridden paint method should use `@Override` notation & call the super method. 6) GUIs should be started on EDT.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I am still working on this, and definitely have a lot to improve.

Comment: When would you like to display this text?!